# Syntax error writing Spark dataframe to Impala table

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, jdbc, impala

I want to write a Spark dataframe to an Impala table, but syntax errors occur on the types of the columns.

This is an example of the code in Pyspark:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 'row1'),
        (2, 'row2'),
    ],
    ['col1', 'col2']
)

df.write.format('jdbc').option('url','jdbc:impala://172.25.0.1:21050/default').option('driver','com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver').option('dbtable','test').save()
```

And this is the error that appears:

```
Caused by: com.cloudera.impala.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:
CREATE TABLE test ("col1" BIGINT , "col2" TEXT )
                   ^
Encountered: STRING LITERAL
Expected: DEFAULT, IDENTIFIER

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
), Query: CREATE TABLE test ("col1" BIGINT , "col2" TEXT ).
        ... 50 more
```

I have tried numerous alternatives for creating the Spark dataframe and for writing mode using JDBC but I always get this error. How could I solve this?

Comment: looks like spark is creating a query with double quoted column name. Can you remove it - and replace using single quote or may be nothing.

Comment: How could i remove the quotes from the column names? The query is automatically generated by Spark using the command "df.write.format('jdbc')..."

Comment: hmm, thats what i was thinking. may be there is some way to tell hive to ignore double quotes. i have seen people uses double quote aswell.

Comment: has this problem been solved in the meantime? Asking because I am facing it too...